# how do i display default products before filtering in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have an app, where you can get list of products when you click on a category, i'm trying to display all products on default without filtering as soon as the page loads before i click on the category to filter the product,

this is my script tag to filter products under a category

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      categoryID: null,
      categories: [],
      products: [],
      show: null,
      price: null,
     
    };
  },

  methods: {
    productsForCat(cat) {
      return this.products.filter(p => p.category._id === cat);
    },
    displayProd(id) {
      this.show === id ? (this.show = null) : (this.show = id);
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/products").then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.products = res.data.products;
    });

    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/categories").then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.categories = res.data.categories;
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

my template, this is how i display my filtered products, when i click the category it displays the products

```
 <div
        class=""
        v-for="category in categories"
        :key="category._id"
      >
        <span @click="displayProd(category._id)">{{category.type}}</span>
        <div
          v-if="category._id === show"
        >
          <div>
   <div
           v-for="product in productsForCat(category._id)"
              :key="product._id"
            >
{{product.title}} 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

how can i display all my products in the database before i click the category which displays the filtered products, for example i have two tabs , one tab to display my filtered category and the other to display all products on default before clicking my category to display products

Comment: `v-for="product in products"` would show all products

Comment: You're filtering products in the `productsForCat(cat)` function. For displaying all the products you've to use `v-for` directive first in a div like this `v-for="product in products"` and then use `v-for="product in productsForCat(category._id)"` for filtering with `@click="displayProd(category._id)"` in another/nested div.